# Spock test in GEB cookies using where clause

Tags: cookies, where-clause, spock, geb

I've configured some `geb` tests to check a different messages depending on the login attempt in my web app. Since the message and the input fields will change at the third login attempt.

The login is a two step login based on password send to a specific phone number, so in the first page **LoginPage** the user introduces their **Id** and **phoneNumber**, then it's redirected to the second page **ValidationLoginPage** where the user introduces the received password.

I want to check that in the second page the user can only introduces three bad passwords and at fourth attempt the input to introduce a password will disappear and a different message indicating that there are no more attempts it's showed.

To check this I prepared a test which introduces the **Id** and **phoneNumber** at the `given:` clause, and  using `where:` clause it introduces a bad password three times. Since `where:` repeat all test I try to control the part to repeat using injected variable like in `where:` so I've something like:

```java
def "Test max loging attempts"(){
  given:
    if(loginAttempt == 1)
      to LoginPage
      loginModule.startLogin(cfg.user.id,cfg.user.phone)
    }
  when:
    at LoginValidationPage
    assert  $('div.box_id_header h3').text() == 'Verify your code'
    assert  $('#code').css('display').contains('block')
    loginModule.verifyPassword('WRONGPASSWORD')
  then:
    at LoginValidationPage
    println "Attempt ${loginAttempt}"
    if(loginAttempt == 4){
      // last attempt
      assert    $('#code').css('display') == 'none' 
      assert  $('#divCodeErrorMsg').text().contains('No more attempts')
    }else{
      assert    $('#code').css('display').contains('block')
      assert  $('#divCodeErrorMsg').text().contains('Wrong password. Try again.')
    }
  where:            
    loginAttempt << (1..4)
}
```

My problem is, that `cookies` are cleared for each `where:` iteration, thought the message and the behavior is not which I expect. I don't want to configure `autoClearCookies=false` in `GebConfig.groovy` file since I've another tests where this feature is necessary. There is a way to avoid the clear cookies for this method using spock `def setupSpec() {}` method and reactivate in `def cleanupSpec() {}` method?

Additionally it's also possible to use `where:` in a cleaner way avoiding to check the `loginAttempt` variable to avoid run `given:` part multiple times, or there is a better approach not using `where:` at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you maybe misunderstand and thus abuse Spock's `where:` block. It is designed to parametrise a feature method and each run of that method comprises an independent feature. If you `@Unroll` your feature, even for each set of `where:` parameters a new method is generated. Because features should be independent of each other and theoretically be able run run in any given order or even in parallel, test fixtures need to be reset in order to run them. This is what happens with your cookies because you abuse the `where:` feature to implement a simple loop.

There are other little problems in your code, such as the non-asserted `at` check in the `when:` block. Even if `at` yields `false`, it has no consequence there if you do not use `assert`. You can only skip `assert` in `then:` or `expect:` blocks, but not in `given:` or `when:` and also not inside closures or helper methods which I will both use in my sample code.

How about this?

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.foo

import geb.spock.GebReportingSpec

class LoginTest extends GebReportingSpec {
  def loginModule = new LoginModule()
  def cfg = new Config()

  def "Test max login attempts"() {
    given: "we are at the login page"
    browser.config.autoClearCookies = false
    to LoginPage

    when: "logging in 4x with wrong credentials"
    (1..4).each {
      loginWithWrongCredentials(it, it < 4)
    }

    then: "we get a 'no more attempts' error message"
    $('#codi').css('display') == 'none'
    $('#divCodiValidacioError').text().contains('No more attempts')
  }

  def loginWithWrongCredentials(int loginAttempt, boolean checkForWrongPasswordMessage) {
    println "Login attempt ${loginAttempt}"
    loginModule.startLogin(cfg.user.id, cfg.user.phone)
    assert at(LoginValidationPage)
    assert $('div.box_id_header h3').text() == 'Verify your code'
    assert $('#code').css('display').contains('block')
    loginModule.verifyPassword('WRONGPASSWORD')
    assert at(LoginValidationPage)
    if (checkForWrongPasswordMessage) {
      assert $('#codi').css('display').contains('block')
      assert $('#divCodiErrorMsg').text().contains('Wrong password. Try again.')
    }
  }
}
```

I would also recommend to move the content asserts from `loginWithWrongCredentials` into helper methods of `LoginValidationPage` where they rather belong and just call them from the test.

Comment: I agree that the code in this question seems to be abusing `where:` blocks which should be used for parametrisation and not looping. Note that you don’t necesarily have to assert at checks if only [implicit assertions](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#at-verification) are enabled.

Comment: Good catch, @erdi! OTOH you are the Geb God and I am only an occasional user. So I am not going to argue here. ;-)

Comment: Ouch... you're totally right, I was trying to keep the test clear using `where:`... now I realize that `where: ` is to run parametritzed test. It's simply like `@RunWith(Parameterized.class)` do in junit. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Finally disabling the `autoClearCookies` in the `setup` step I get the desired behavior.

```
def setup() {
    browser.getConfig().setAutoClearCookies(false)      
}
```

However surprisingly if I use `setupSpec()` method, seems that it not works, since only first `where:` iteration has `autoClearCookies=false` and the rest has `autoClearCookies=true`.